# '/etc/hosts' , http links are redirecting, but https links are not redirecting

Tags: dns, iptables, hosts

I edited /etc/hosts file and entered below information :

```
127.0.0.1    test.com  //working

127.0.0.1    https://test.com //not working .
```

from the above info, *http://test.com* is redirecting to 127.0.0.1, but *https://test.com* is not redirecting to 127.0.0.1 . Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: I've got the same issue. Have you solved?

Answer (score 10):

`/etc/hosts` does not care about protocols, it handles host names. Moreover, `//` is not a comment character in `/etc/hosts`. See

```
man hosts
```

for details.

```
127.0.0.1 test.com
```

should be enough for redirecting both http and https. Do you run a service listening for https connections on your localhost?

Comment: leave those commnents, i just entered them here .
My use case is,in my website some parts of the code can be tested only with the domain name, and my website uses https . So, if it is just http, i can test locally with the domain name . But as it is https, I am unable to test locally .

Comment: Once more: Is your local webserver configured to handle https requests?

Answer (score 1):

I thought I was having a similar problem.

For anyone who makes the same silly mistake I did...

I was testing a new webserver by rerouting the requests to a different IP by /etc/hosts.

I did tail -f access_log on my web server and saw all my test requests, except the https ones.  I spent a few minutes trying to figure that out.

Finally, I realized that I log SSL requests to a different file.
Those log entries were working just fine, in access_ssl_log.  Doh!